# Can inaccessibility be captured in relational flat set theory?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

Working in a first order theory of flat sets (axioms given below) , which is a theory with a single non-trivial tier of membership, that is all sets are nonempty sets of Quine atoms, plus having some of the atoms being directional elements (which serve as ordered pairs between elements), plus having a well ordering $R$ over the whole universe of atoms; what I call as "*Relational flat set theory*". IF we define the cardinality of a set $A$, denoted as |A|, as the $R$-maximal element of the $\subseteq$-minimal bi-ended initial segment that is bijective to $A$, where a *bi-ended initial segment* is defined as a set closed under $<^R$ and that has an $R$-maximal element. And define regular cardinal as:

$$regular (\kappa) \iff (\exists X: \kappa=|X|) \land (\neg \exists S: \kappa = \lim(S) \land |S| < \kappa) $$

Lets define inaccessible cardinal as:

$$ inaccessible (\kappa) \iff \kappa > \omega \land \not \exists \lambda (\kappa = \lambda+1) \land regular(\kappa)$$

Where $``<,lim, +"$ are all defined in the usual manner but with respect to relation $R$

Now lets add the following formula to the axiom of well ordering.

**Inaccessibles:** $\exists \kappa : inaccessible (\kappa)$

> Questions:
>
> 1. would those notions of regular cardinals and weak inaccessibility correspond to the same notions defined in standard set theory?
> 2. if they do so, then this would mean that this theory is NOT interpretable in ZFC, then can this theory interpret ZFC? or is it incomparable with it?

So the idea here is that if inaccessibility can be captured in a flat milieu? and if it would enable constructing a model of ZFC in that harsh restriction on set structure, perhaps by defining $L$ within it, thereby interpreting power indirectly? If that is the case then this would mean that Relational flat set theory has all the resources that ordinary set theory have? And a hierarchy of sets is not essentially needed?!

---

**Relational Flat Set Theory:**

Language: First order logic with equality $``="$, membership $``\in"$, and directional linking $L$, the latter is a partial two place function symbol, where $l=L(a,b)$ is read as $l$ links $a$ to $b$.

Axioms:

**Extensionality** $\forall  ( z \in x \leftrightarrow z \in y) \to x=y$

**Membership:** $x \in y \to x=\{x\}$

**Actuality:** $\forall x \exists y (y \in x)$

**Composition:** $\exists x (\exists!y (y \in x) \phi) \to \exists s \forall x (x \in s \leftrightarrow \exists!y (y \in x) \phi)$

Let $S$ be the set of all singletons.

**Naturality:** $l=L(a,b) \to l,a,b \in S $

**Links:** $\forall  a,b \in S \exists l : l=L(a,b)  $

**Direction:** $L(a,b) = L(c,d) \to (a=c \land b=d) $

**Well ordering:** $\exists R: R \text{ well orders } S$

Comment: Does your axiom of Actuality mean that there is no empty set in this theory? That would already seem to break any direct interpretation of ZFC by this theory...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, of course it would! definitely the interpretation is not direct, since after all we are having only one tier of non-trivial membership, and Quine atoms,.. so yes the interpretation is definitely indirect.

Comment: I'm just struggling to see how even an indirect interpretation would work here. Can you offer any sort of an atlas as to how you see a subset of the ZFC axioms being interpreted in this theory? My first instinct says that the $R$-minimal element of $S$ 'has to' represent the empty set, but I'm not really seeing any sensible candidates for $\in$...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, the only idea is a vague one that if $L$ can in some way be defined in this theory, then this can indirectly interpret ZFC. The existence of an inaccessible "in the view of this theory" must add some work. But I have no detailed plan.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, there is no problem with interpreting the empty set and the hereditarily finite sets of ZFC, this theory clearly interpret second order arithmetic and thus PA, and PA can interpret ZFC-Infinity, by constructing a model of ZFC -Infinity in which all sets are hereditarily finite (see: http://web.mat.bham.ac.uk/R.W.Kaye/publ/papers/finitesettheory/finitesettheory.pdf) But I think this theory can go way beyond that as to possibly interpret the whole of ZFC through defining L in it, but I'm not really sure of that.